# How to properly using EOF?

Tags: c, io, eof

I have question about EOF.

First of all, I am coding a simple program that is coping/printing the user's input.

However, the program copies the EOF also in the output.

For an example, my O.S is Window and my EOF works when I type (Enter -> cntrl + z -> Enter) in order. If I input "Hello" + Enter + EOF key combination, the output prints the weird letter('?') at the end of the copied user input.

[image]

How can I get rid of the '?' at the end of the output, and why is it happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void copy(char to[], char from[]);

main()
{
    int i;
    int c;

    char origin[10];
    char copied[10];

    for(i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; ++i)
    {
        origin[i] = c;
    }

    copy(copied, origin);


    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        putchar(copied[i]); 



}

void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        i++;
}
```

Comment: Not the problem, but you should use a standard `int main(void)` instead of `main()`

Comment: `EOF` is *not* a value of `char` type (e.g. on computers where `char`-s are `unsigned`, `EOF` might be -1). So you cannot copy `EOF`, by definition!

Comment: A good question. Just using a screen shot is a pity. Please paste text as text. To do to from windows in the CMD-window enable "Quick Edit Mode"  in the window's properties' options TAB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not related to `EOF` at all, there are multiple issues in your code leading to potential undefined behavior and unwanted side-effects:

- The reading loop continues up to the end of file: if the input stream is longer than 10 bytes, the code will cause a buffer overrun, storing bytes beyond the end of the `origin` array. This is a first case of undefined behavior.
- The local array `origin` is uninitialized, so its contents are indeterminate. You do not store a null terminator into it after the bytes read from `stdin`.
- In the `copy` function, you rely on a null terminator to stop the copying loop, but since none was stored there, you access uninitialized contents after all bytes read from `stdin` have been copied. The null terminator test is combined with the assignment in `while((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')`. Accessing uninitialized data has undefined behavior. Furthermore, you keep reading from `origin` until a null terminator is found, causing further undefined behavior if you end up reading beyond the end of the array, and even more so when writing beyond the end of the `copied` array.
- The final loop outputs all 10 elements of the `copied` array.
- Even if the array `origin` may by chance contain null bytes at the end, thus preventing undefined behavior in the `copy` function. The output loop would still output funny characters as you would not stop at the null terminator, but instead print it to `stdout`, and again have undefined behavior when you read uninitialized contents at the end of `copied` after that.
- Also note that the prototype for `main` without arguments is `int main(void)`. The syntax you used, without a return type, was common in the '70 and '80s but is now obsolete and should not be used anymore.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void copy(char to[], char from[]);

int main(void) {
    int i;
    int c;
    char origin[10];
    char copied[10];

    for (i = 0; i < 10 - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF; i++) {
        origin[i] = c;
    }
    origin[i] = '\0';

    copy(copied, origin);

    for (i = 0; copied[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        putchar(copied[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void copy(char to[], char from[]) {
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        i++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to NUL-terminate `origin`. So you invoke Undefined Behavior during copying. Use the following code to get input instead:

```
for(i = 0; i < 9 && (c = getchar()) != EOF; ++i) /* `i < 9` to prevent array overruns */
{
    origin[i] = c;
}
origin[i] = '\0'; /* NUL-terminate your string */
```

Also change the printing code to:

```
for(i = 0; copied[i] != '\0'; i++) /* Print until a NUL-terminator */
    putchar(copied[i]);
```

Comment: No, this is the correct answer. A local array is not properly initialized by default (so the programmer should think of initializing it)

Comment: The `origin[i] = '\0';` statement is correctly null-terminating the string in `origin`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I needed three reparsings to see that 0 IS copied. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are unconditionally outputting all 10 members of your array.
You could fix by appending the often used `'\0'` at the end of the letters to output.
With a

```
origin[i] = '\0';
```

after reading in.

And finally outputting until that marker, instead of everything

```
for(i = 0; copied[i]!='\0'; i++)
```

This keeps your assumption that the arrays are large enough to keep the input (including the added `'\0'`). You should however protect against that, e.g by using a dual condition for any loop, checking against accessing beyound the highest allowed array index.

Comment: May also want to comment on how dangerous `for(i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF; ++i)` is... Input of `"Hello Newb<nasty shellcode>"` could be quite bad.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an IDE (probably CodeBlocks) which is using page buffer between subsequent IO operation and that's why you actually get the output.

Next, you are forcing to print all ten elements of the array in the output for loop which is bad coding practice.

This simple snippet could help you

```
scanf("%10[^\n]s",input);
```

Use it to read input from file ./youpro < file_name_where_to_fetch_input

Thanks to David C. Rankin in the comment to mention the error.

Comment: I think OPs description of how they input `EOF` is plausible.

Comment: Maybe, it is. I am not from windows background... and my answer is more towards Linux and in general when compiling from terminal... You can't do these magical combinations to enter EOF... So, an std practice should be followed and so as my ans. Might I be wrong on windows..

Comment: *"there is no way to enter 'EOF' as input"*?? Of course there is. `Ctrl+d` on Linux generates a manual `EOF` and `Ctrl+z` does the same on windoze. But see: [CTRL+Z does not generate EOF in Windows 10](http://proc-x.com/2017/06/ctrlz-does-not-generate-eof-in-windows-10/)

Comment: You are still out on a skinny branch regarding guessing at the IDE (which isn't really relevant anyway), but good first effort. Remember, when answering on StackOverflow, you step into the roll of Teacher. You want to make sure you are one of the good ones, and not one of the teachers that have left us all more confused than when we started the lesson. Keep up the good effort and always work to be thorough and correct.

Comment: The conversion specifier for character classes does **not** have a trailing `s`, and the number specified must be one less than the size of the array. It should be written `scanf("%9[^\n]", origin);`. Furthermore, this `scanf()` will fail if the user enters an empty line, causing undefined behavior if the return value of `scanf()` is ignored.